# Android Strange Display Multipled [virtualbox]

Tags: applications, screen, virtualbox

I don't know what's the category of this problem. But i only encountered this in several apps that runs under my emulator of Android 4.1.1 under VirtualBox.

[image: Screen is multiplied strangely]

What should i do to resolve this problem?

Comment: Does your graphics card/driver support the emulator?

Comment: @esQmo, i dont think it's about graphic card. Bcoz the display, it works fine on another app... home screen, settings, etc... but only several apps showing this kind of strange thing. Any other clue?